# how to use sass variables from a CDN

Tags: css, webpack, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I've a project that uses `create-react-app` and a remotely hosted `colors.scss` file that only has the definition of colors inside (content below).

```
$color-blue: #2281ff;
$color-cyan: #11a0f2;
$color-lue-light: #cfd7fc;
```

Next I've an `index.scss` that looks the following way:

```
@import url('http://url.domain/colors.scss');

body: {
  background-color: $color-blue;
}
```

When the app is being build I get the following error

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-blue".
        on line 4 of src/index.scss
>>   background-color: $color-blue;
```

this is when using `node-sass`

Next I've tried changing `node-sass` to `dart-sass` which is just `sass` so ran `npm uninstall node-sass` and then `npm install sass`

my file looked like this

```
@use url('http://url.domain/colors.scss');

body: {
  background-color: $color-blue;
}
```

this yielded an error

```
SassError: Expected string.
  ╷
1 │ @use url('http://url.domain/color.scss');
```

rewriting the import to

```
@use "http://url.domain/color.scss";
```

yielded

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "http://url.domain/color.scss";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is it not possible to use variables from a remote source? Or am I missing something?

NOTE: `http://url.domain/color.scss` is an abstracted version of the link, when the real one is pasted into the browser I can see the correct stylesheet with variables loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use the variables defined in the remote SCSS file. We ran into a similar issue. So, we downloaded the remote scss file as part of the build process and referenced the downloaded file as a local file.